# Table numbering repeats in new section

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, caption

All the tables are numbered correctly in document Sections 1-4 (Table 1-6) and Section 5 (Table 7), but the following Tables in Section 6 go back to Table #6 and on from there, as if Section 5 hadn't happened. I have tried deleting and re-inserting the caption for the table in Section 6 and I have tried selecting the whole document and hitting F9 to update fields, with no changes. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the SEQ fields behind the table caption is being reset or skipped in some form or another. To have a look press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> to show field codes and look for any SEQ fields belonging to "Table" which don't look like they are part of a proper caption. Additionally you can try looking for any SEQ fields which include the "\r" switch which can restart the numbering to a different value.

Comment: Very handy! I found 2 tables with no SEQ fields. Once I copy pasted the code from earlier tables, it still didn't fix the problem immediately. However, when I went through as I had tried before, deleting and replacing the Table captions, this time they all came up with the correct numbering. Thank-you very much!

Answer (score 0):

go to the TAB VIEW -> Outline. Set Show Level: to "Level 9" That gives you a outline of all paragraph numbers recognized by word. Make sure that you have not used some sort of other numbering scheme that was falsely assumed by word to be a paragraph number.

Get rid of all unplanned sentences / numbering / etc. by using the ->> in the Outline Tools section.